# How to solve the Android MediaCodec error after setting "csd-0" and "csd-1"?

Tags: android, android-camera, encode, android-mediacodec

I use the MediaCodec to encode video stream and i need to set the "csd-0" and "csd-1" as following according to [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)):

```
byte[] sps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 100, 0, 40, -84, 52, -59, 1, -32, 17, 31, 120, 11, 80, 16, 16, 31, 0, 0, 3, 3, -23, 0, 0, -22, 96, -108 };
byte[] pps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 104, -18, 60, -128 };
MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(sps));
format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(pps));
...
```

But i got an error:

```
format: {frame-rate=15, height=1280, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=31,capacity=31], color-format=2130708361, width=720, bitrate=819200, csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=8,capacity=8], mime=video/avc, i-frame-interval=3}
E/ACodec  ( 2692): [OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder] ERROR(0x80001006)
E/MediaCodec( 2692): Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001006, internalError -2147483648)
```

PS:
The os version is Android 4.4.2 and soc is Exynos5430

Comment: Hi @fadden, could you please give me some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Did you try by removing the `nalu` start code from the array? The error is `0x80001006` means that the underlying `OMX` component is returning `OMX_ErrorNotImplemented`

Comment: @Ganesh Did you mean the `sps` and `pps` ?

Comment: yes.. please try by removing the start codes from the arrays

Comment: @Ganesh The reason i added the `sps` and `pps` is that MTK engineer said mtk soc need the `sps` and `pps`, otherwise the video is abnormal. It can work after removing the `sps` and `pps`, but abnormal display.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I am missing something. From your logs, `E/ACodec  ( 2692): [OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder] ERROR(0x80001006)`. Are you trying to create an `encoder` or `decoder`? If you are trying to create an `encoder`, you don't require the `csd`. The `encoder` itself will generate it. If you are creating a `decoder`, please try by removing only 0,0,0,1 from each of the arrays.