# Android: MediaCodec: dequeueBuffer failed: BAD_VALUE(-22)

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

i'm trying to decode data that i send through TCP.

I successfully managed to fill in the decoder.
But when i try to get the output to render it on a surfaceView. i get this error:

```
dequeueBuffer failed: BAD_VALUE(-22)
```

Also, outputBufferIdde is always equal to -1 (try again later)

this is my code :

```
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2968);
    Log.d(TAG,"server accept");
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
    InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();

    inputBuffersde = decodec.getInputBuffers();
    Log.d(TAG, "encodeDecode 1");
    DecoderRunnable decoderRunnable=new DecoderRunnable(decodec,infode);
    new Thread(decoderRunnable).start();


    while (true) {
        dataSizes=new byte[4];
        inputStream.read(dataSizes,0,4);
        dataSize=ByteBuffer.wrap(dataSizes).getInt();
        Log.d(TAG,"size: "+dataSize);
        totalLen=0;
        data= new byte[dataSize];

        for(;totalLen<dataSize;) {
            len=inputStream.read(data, totalLen, dataSize-totalLen);
            totalLen+=len;
            Log.d(TAG,"totalLen: "+totalLen+" ,len: "+len);
        }

        int inputBufferIdde = decodec.dequeueInputBuffer(5000);
        Log.d(TAG,"inputBufferIdde: "+inputBufferIdde);
        if (inputBufferIdde >= 0) {
            Log.d(TAG,"inputBufferIdde: "+inputBufferIdde);
            inputBuffersde[inputBufferIdde].clear();
            inputBuffersde[inputBufferIdde].rewind();
            inputBuffersde[inputBufferIdde].put(data);
            decodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIdde, 0, inputBuffersde[inputBufferIdde].position(), System.nanoTime(), 0);
        }
    }
} catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

DecoderRunnable looks like this :

```
public DecoderRunnable(MediaCodec decodec, MediaCodec.BufferInfo infode) {
    this.decodec = decodec;
    this.infode = infode;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        int outputBufferIdde = decodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(infode, 5000);
        Log.d(TAG, "outputBufferIdde : " + outputBufferIdde);
        if (outputBufferIdde >= 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "encodeDecode 7");

            decodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIdde, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing NALUs to your decoder? have you configured your decoder with SPS & PPS ?

Comment: The byte[] data is sent directly from an encoder with the same parameters.

Comment: Ok, but do you send SPSPPS that you get from the encoder output format (when it get configured) and configure the decoder with ? `format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(sps));`...

Comment: SPS & PPS are used to solve problems of packets being lost, but i use TCP so it shouldn't be a problem ?

Comment: Not only, the decoder requires SPS PPS (codec-specific-data) to be configured properly before submiting frames... take a look at codec-specific-data section here:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec

Comment: I've tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448654/how-to-solve-the-android-mediacodec-error-after-setting-csd-0-and-csd-1)  and i still get the same error

Comment: You can't apply this, you have to get CSDs values from the encoder, when the format get changed, and in the decoder side you have to test if the data you receive is a csd ( SPS : byte[4] = 103, PPS : byte[4] = 104), if is the case, you can queue it to the decoder with flag BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG, and after that feed your decoder input buffer with NALUs

Comment: tu t'en sors? :)

Comment: it finally worked but the problem wasn't SPS & PPS, it was that i shouldn't initialize the decoder, i must only use initialize the mediaFormat but not specify the bitrate or colorFormat since i already set that in the encoder.